# Finding index of elements in an array of arrays

Tags: arrays, ruby, indexing, find

I have an array of arrays:

```
[
  [0,0,0,0],
  [0,1,0,0],
  [0,0,0,1],
  [0,0,0,0]
]
```

I want to find the index (row and column) of the items with value `1`.  How can I do this? I need these values so that I can manipulate the cells at either side of the `1`s. I looked at `find.index` method, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I wonder why people keep using a nested array for these kinds of situations. A flat array is much easier to handle.

Comment: When you give an example please assign a variable to each input object. That way the variable can be referenced in answers and comments. All but one of the answers begins by defining the array. Had you written `arr =[[0,0....]]` none of that would be needed--answers would have just referenced `arr`. I realize you're new to SO. This is just a tip, not a criticism.

Answer (score 3):

Not that fancy, but you could use two loops:

```
ary = [
  [0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 1, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 1],
  [0, 0, 0, 0]
]

result = []
ary.each_with_index do |row, i|
  row.each_with_index do |value, j|
    result << [i, j] if value == 1
  end
end
result
#=> [[1, 1], [2, 3]]
```

Comment: ...or `ary.each_index {|i| ary.first.each_index {|j| result << [i,j] if ary[i][j] == 1}}`.

Answer (score 2):

```
a = [
  [0,0,0,0],
  [0,1,0,0],
  [0,0,0,1],
  [0,0,0,0]
].flatten

a.each.with_index.select{|e, _| e == 1}.map{|_, i| i.divmod(4)}
# => [[1, 1], [2, 3]]
```

To be interpreted as (row 1, column 1) and (row 2, column 3).

Comment: @Stefan It is possible to get `4` as the length of the first element of the original array, but my suggestion is to have a flat array from the beginning, with the additional information of `4`.

Comment: Either that or a hash with `[x, y] => value` pairs

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the [Matrix](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html) class.

```
require 'matrix'

arr = [
  [0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 1, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 1],
  [0, 0, 0, 0]
]    

target = 1

Matrix[*arr].each_with_index.with_object([]) { |(e,row,col),a|
  a << [row,col] if e==target }
  #=> [[1, 1], [2, 3]]
```

I like how this reads.

Comment: Thanks for all your help everyone

Comment: A combination of `select` and `map` would also work: `m.each_with_index.select { |e, r, c| e == 1 }.map { |e, r, c| [r, c] }`

Answer (score 0):

Ruby has a very flexible, functional style `Enumerable` module which is included in many of the standard collections (Arrays, Hashes, Sets). You can find the documentation [at ruby-doc.org](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html).

A nice one-liner to solve this in max #rows * 2 #columns time would be the following:

```
matrix
  .each.with_index
  .inject([]) { |acc, (el,idx)| el.include?(1) ? acc.push([idx, el.index(1)]) : acc }
# => [[1,1],[2,3]]
```

Comment: This doesn't work if a row contains more than one `1`

Answer (score 0):

```
z = [
  [0,0,0,0],
  [0,1,0,0],
  [0,0,0,1],
  [0,0,0,0]
]
```

First, let's find the matching rows:

```
rows = z.each_with_index.select { |row, index| row.include? 1}.map(&:last)
# => [1, 2]
```

And then for each row let's find the index of the matching `1`:

```
cols = rows.map {|row| z[row].each_with_index.select { |item, index| item == 1}.map(&:last) }
# => [[1], [3]]
```

If we want, we can then combine them using `zip`:

```
rows.zip(cols)
# => [[1, [1]], [2, [3]]]
```

The above works even if a row of `z` contains multiple occurrences of `1`

For example if we had:

```
z = [
  [1,0,0,1],
  [0,1,0,0],
  [0,0,0,1],
  [1,1,1,0]
]
```

then

```
rows = z.each_with_index.select { |row, index| row.include? 1}.map(&:last)
# => [0, 1, 2, 3]
cols = rows.map {|row| z[row].each_with_index.select { |item, index| item == 1}.map(&:last) }
# => [[0, 3], [1], [3], [0, 1, 2]]
rows.zip(cols)
# => [[0, [0, 3]], [1, [1]], [2, [3]], [3, [0, 1, 2]]]
```

Comment: Good point for implicitly pointing out a flaw in Timon Vonk's answer.